# Failing to build EDK (development environment for UEFI)

Tags: c, visual-studio, uefi

I followed the build instructions [here](https://github.com/tianocore/tianocore.github.io/wiki/Windows-systems). But once I run the build this is what I get:

```
C:\edk2>build
Build environment: Windows-post2008Server-6.2.9200
Build start time: 11:52:03, Jan.26 2016

WORKSPACE        = c:\edk2
ECP_SOURCE       = c:\edk2\edkcompatibilitypkg
EDK_SOURCE       = c:\edk2\edkcompatibilitypkg
EFI_SOURCE       = c:\edk2\edkcompatibilitypkg
EDK_TOOLS_PATH   = c:\edk2\basetools
EDK_TOOLS_BIN    = c:\edk2\basetools\bin\win32


Architecture(s)  = IA32
Build target     = DEBUG
Toolchain        = VS2013

Active Platform          = c:\edk2\MdeModulePkg\MdeModulePkg.dsc

Processing meta-data ........... done!
Building ... c:\edk2\MdePkg\Library\BaseDebugPrintErrorLevelLib\BaseDebugPrintErrorLevelLib.inf [IA32]


build...
 : error 7000: Failed to start command
        C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Vc\bin\nmake.exe /nologo tbuild [c:\edk2\Build\MdeModule\DEBUG_VS2
013\IA32\MdePkg\Library\BaseDebugPrintErrorLevelLib\BaseDebugPrintErrorLevelLib]


build...
 : error F002: Failed to build module
        c:\edk2\MdePkg\Library\BaseDebugPrintErrorLevelLib\BaseDebugPrintErrorLevelLib.inf [IA32, VS2013, DEBUG]

- Failed -
Build end time: 11:52:15, Jan.26 2016
Build total time: 00:00:11
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: It's recommanded that you should download UDK2015 Release.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem most likely is that you do not have nmake.exe located under C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Vc\bin, so just like the first error says, it "Failed to start command". Follow the path and see if nmake.exe is there.

The same build environment fails on my machine too because nmake.exe is located not under "c:\Program Files\...", but under "c:\Program Files (x86)\...". So if you update the target.txt file under c:\edk2\Conf\ to set the tool chain VS2013x86:

```
TOOL_CHAIN_TAG  = VS2013x86
```

then it should build properly. In any case, this troubleshooting step should get you much further in understanding the cause of the failure.

Comment: Very helpful--I didn't realize the connection between the x86 suffix and "Program Files (x86)"